# How to supply new options for select on change of current select in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**"Can any body just let me know to call a function on change of select box inside ng-repeat, which sends back data that is available for second select box below first but not for all"**
suppose I have 2 products

```
product 1  
select1-on change of this
select2-this should change

product2
select1-on change of this
select2-this should change
```

but whats happening is

```
 product 1  
    select1-on change of this
    select2-is changing

    product2
    select1-
    select2-this is also changing
```

can anybody help me with this?

I have a ng-repeat loop in which I have 2 select boxes, for first select box I am getting data from api call, when user changes any option from first select box I have to get code and match with its code entire data and supply options to second select box.

But the main problem entire thing I am looping in side ng-repeat so if there are 2 products or more on select of first select box from first product it changing all second select box data for all products.

Here is my code

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="product in products ">
    <div ng-show="IsVisible" class="form-group row sub-div vsub-div-fw">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 fd">
                                                <p class="cust-label" for="pay_opt">Select a plan.</p>
                                                <select ng-change="getPaymentOptions(orders.selectedSub[$index],index)" ng-init="orders.selectedSub[$index] = product.recurrence[0].code"  ng-model="orders.selectedSub[$index]" ng-options="sub.code as sub.name for sub in product.recurrence "  class="input-lg form-control select-community-list" id="pay_opt">
                                                <!-- <option value="">Select Subscription Plan</option> -->
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row sub-div vsub-div-fw">
                                             <div class="col-sm-6 fd">
                                                <p class="cust-label" for="">Select a payment option.</p>
                                                <select  required="required" ng-model="orders.selectedPayment[$index]" class="input-lg selectPaymentOption paymentOption{{$index}} form-control"  id="" >
                                                <option ng-init="orders.selectedPayment[$index] = product.payment_options[0]" ng-repeat="opt in product.payment_options" value="{{opt}}"  class="myPaymentBox">{{opt.split("_").join(" ") }}</option> 
                                                </select>
                                                <p id="paymentOptionErr{{$index}}" class="alert alert-danger product-error-msg"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Please select payment option to proceed.</p>
                                            </div>
</div>
```

js code

```
$scope.getPaymentOptions=function(plan,i){
                angular.forEach($scope.products,function(p){
                    angular.forEach(p.recurrence,function(r){
                        if (r.code==plan) {
                            p.payment_options=r.payment_type;
                            $scope.orders.selectedPayment[i] = r.payment_type[0];
                        };
                    });
                })
            }
```

The above function is called when we change first select box, to get options for second select box. but when we have more products, changing product one's first select box will change all second select box options. how to make unique on change function?

Comment: can you setup jsfidle example with code...

Comment: Sorry code is huge can you just let me know how to handle function call on change of select but in ng-repeat?